# Form-data is not binding to viewmodel with a generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an application written using `C#` on the top of ASP.NET Core 5.0.

I have the following view-model

```
public class TestVM 
{
   public Name  { get; set; }

   public MenuViewModel<string> State { get; set;}

   public TestVM()
   {
       State = MenuViewModel<string>();
   }
}
```

Here is a stripped down version of my `MenuViewModel`

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    [BindNever]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class MenuViewModel<T> : MenuViewModel
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

The problem, is when the post request comes in, the `viewModel.State.Value` is null. When I evaluate `Request.Form` I do see the key `State.Value` with the correct value of `CA`

Here is a stripped down of my action method in the controller.

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Store(TestVM viewModel)
{

   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     // do some
   }

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

How can I bind the form data from the request to `State.Value` property correctly?

**Updated** I created an editor-template to allow me to render the MenuVieModel. The `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MenuViewModel.cshtml` contains the following code

```
@model dynamic

@{
    if (!(Model is MenuViewModel m))
    {
        return;
    }

    dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    obj.Class = "form-control";
    if (Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
    {
        obj.Required = true;
    }
}

@Html.DropDownList("Value", m.Options, Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Placeholder, obj)
```

Comment: Show relevant view part.

Comment: @mxmissile  please check out the updated post

Comment: How do you render the MenuViewModel.cshtml?Could you please share the get method?And what is your `m.Options` in razor view?When I copy your code,it would make error:`'MenuViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Options' and no accessible extension method 'Options' accepting a first argument of type 'MenuViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.Does your MenuViewModel contains Options property?

Answer (score 1):

Firsly,you need know that for each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix.

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class TestVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MenuViewModel<string> State { get; set; }
    public TestVM()
    {
        State =new MenuViewModel<string>();
    }
}
public class MenuViewModel
{
    [BindNever]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class MenuViewModel<T> : MenuViewModel
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model dynamic

@{
    if (!(Model is MenuViewModel m))
    {
        return;
    }

    dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    obj.Class = "form-control";
    if (Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
    {
        obj.Required = true;
    }
}
<form asp-action="Store">

          @*change here,And I do not find Options in your MenuViewModel,So I change it to Items*@
    @Html.DropDownList("State.Value", m.Items, Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Placeholder, obj)
    <input type="submit" value="post" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MenuViewModel<string>()
    {
        Items = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "-1", Text = "--- Select ---" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "org1", Text = "org1" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "org2", Text = "org2" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "org3", Text = "org3" }
            }
    };        
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Store(TestVM viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do some
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hum, so my code as is is working for you? I am wondering why `Value` is always null for me even when the request has `State.Value`.

Comment: No,your code does not work for me.And I think you need to share the whole code to me,I could not find `m.Options` in your razor view.Please check my razor view,my code is not same as yours.

Comment: Yes. Sorry that was a copy/paste error. The correct code is m.Items. But the model binding is working for you and not for me. For me State.Value is always null

Comment: Did you change `@Html.DropDownList("Value"` to `@Html.DropDownList("State.Value"`?Also,check my model,the model which you provide is also wrong.Check the constructor and the Name in TestVM.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The issue was that in my code I had `public T Value` instead on `public T Value { get; set; }` which is why Value was always set to null. But for the view to work "Value" should be used not "State.Value"

Comment: Your solution is a bit unbeleivable that in your question the Value contains getter setter.And if you receive the TestVM in action,what you post should be State.Value,this is be design in model binding system.Maybe what you provide in your question still miss something. In the future,I suggest that you could share the correct code which could reproduce the issue,otherwise we could not help you successfully.